# Audible notifications using alarm stream when ring volume is silenced (Android Oreo)

Tags: android, android-notifications, alarm, android-8.0-oreo

I have an existing app that was able to produce an audible notification sound even when the device had its **ring volume silenced** by using the `Alarm` audio stream (assuming the Alarm volume was non-zero).  This worked fine on Android 7.1.2

**After upgrading my device to Oreo** (8.0.0), the notification is **no longer audible** unless the ring volume is non-zero. The **app was unchanged**.

So my attempt to fix this was to recompile against Oreo (SDK 26) APIs and include the new `NotificationChannel` stuff just to see if that helped, which it did not.

Note that this code is executing from within a `Service`.

Here is a code excerpt:

```
int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX;
Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);

NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel("channel1", "Alarms", importance);
mChannel.setDescription("Alarms that alert you immediately");
mChannel.enableLights(true);

mChannel.enableVibration(true);
mChannel.setSound(defaultSoundUri,
   new AudioAttributes.Builder()
      .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
      .setFlags(AudioAttributes.FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED)
      .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
   .build()
);

notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);  

Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this,"channel1")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
        .setContentTitle("Alarm Message")
        .setContentText(messageBody)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri, new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                .setFlags(AudioAttributes.FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build())
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_ALARM)
        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);


Notification n = notificationBuilder.build();
n.flags = n.flags | Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, n);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with this issue. I haven't found out why this is happening, but I worked around this issue using the `MediaPlayer`. I removed the part where the sound is added to the notification and replaced that part with this:

```
        Uri ringtoneUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this.getApplicationContext(), ringtoneUri);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder().setLegacyStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM).build());
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
           public final void onCompletion(MediaPlayer it) {
              mediaPlayer.stop();
              mediaPlayer.release();
           }
        });
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
           public final void onPrepared(MediaPlayer it) {
              mediaPlayer.start();
           }
        });
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issue, but it was popping up on Android 7.1.1

The solution for me was to remove following line

```
.setFlags(AudioAttributes.FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED)
```

I have searched for an explanation why removing this flag works, but I have not found any information what FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED does, except the description from developer documentation, saying

> Flag defining a behavior where the audibility of the sound will be ensured by the system.